# Change a value in a json file using jsonparser

Tags: java, json

I am very new to Java but have figured out how to extract values from a json file - but I can not understand how to change the value.

```
JsonElement staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("file1.json"), JsonElement.class);
String json = gson.toJson(staff);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(json);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement f3obj = ((JsonObject) ((JsonObject) ((JsonArray) jsonObject.get("Options")).get(1)).get("Option").get("Dialog");
```

How can I update the value of "Dialog" in this object?

Comment: Can you share your json as well?

Comment: This is the json file I am using http://pastebin.com/hKi79ZnF

Comment: I have added code which you can use to modify. Please mark correct and upvote if I resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update using below mentioned code.

```
        JsonObject f3obj = ((JsonArray) jsonObject.get("Options")).get(1).getAsJsonObject().get("Option").getAsJsonObject();
        f3obj.addProperty("Dialog", new Integer(10));
        System.out.println(f3obj);
```

I am using Guava library so below mentioned packages are being used.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new Json from the given response values.

```
def jsonData = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.contentAsString)
```

And you can use the JSONObject as follows:

```
JSONObject newStudent  = jsonData.getJSONObject("student");
newStudent.put("name", "John");
```

If you get an Array as a response use the following code:

```
JSONObject newStudent  = jsonData.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("student");
nweStudent.put("name", "John");
```

For building JSON using a builder you can use the Json builder:

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder([
    [type: 'string', values: ['no', 'name', 'here']]
])
```